# Uploading an SQLite database to Google App engine?

Tags: android, sqlite, google-app-engine

In my application I am saving user's data within an **SQlite database** on their device. I want to  add the functionality that whenever WIFI is available the contents of the Database can be uploaded on to Google App engine's **Data Store**.

I want to know if this is possible? And if so, how difficult is it to implement?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible to do that, even more, it's an easy stuff. All you have to do is to create a web application with google app engine, than your android application sends its data to GAE. You can do that using HttpURLConnection to send your data and java servlets to intercept your requests and save your data in datastore. You can also use web services.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that I am not very experienced with servers etc. Do you know of any example code where I could follow a tutorial?

Comment: Here is a tutorial written in french (sorry for that) [link] (http://www.tutos-android.com/webservice-rest-android-appengine-restlet-objectify) that explain how to create an application similar to what you want to do using rest web services. It may seems a complicated example since many technologies are used, but it's not that complicated.

Answer (score 1):

On GAE side, you need to create backend API using [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/) and generate client library for Android devices. Your backend will be responsible to receive the data and save it in datastore. Another alternative will be to use [Cloud Datastore API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/datastore/v1beta2) to interact with datastore directly, but endpoints is a much better option.